# Beginner java programming if-else statements inefficient code

Tags: java, performance, if-statement

My code is correct but it looks too big.I was wondering if it could be more efficient and with even fewer variables.Do you have any hints?Thanks

sample output

Enter three scores: 87 42 94

The lowest score was: 42 
The average without the lowest score is: 90.5 
The grade is: A

```
<code>
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeAverager
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int score1,score2,score3;
       double average,average_no_lowest;

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter three scores: ");
       score1 = keyboard.nextInt();
       score2 = keyboard.nextInt();
       score3 = keyboard.nextInt();

       average = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0;

       System.out.println();
       System.out.println("The average is: " + average);


       if (score1 < score2 && score1 < score3)
             System.out.println("The lowest score was:" + score1);
       else if (score2 < score1 && score2 < score3)
             System.out.println("The lowest score was:" + score2);
       else if (score3 < score1 && score3 < score2)
             System.out.println("The lowest score was:" + score3);



       if (score1 < score2 && score1 < score3){
             average_no_lowest = (score2 + score3)/2.0; 
             System.out.println("The average without the lowest score is: " + average_no_lowest);
             if(average_no_lowest > 90)
                  System.out.print('A');
             else if(average_no_lowest < 90 && average_no_lowest > 80 )
                  System.out.print('B');
             else if(average_no_lowest > 70 && average_no_lowest < 80)
                  System.out.print('C'); 
             else
                  System.out.print('D');
             }
       else if (score2 < score1 && score2 < score3){
             average_no_lowest = (score1 + score3)/2.0;
             System.out.println("The average without the lowest score is: " + average_no_lowest);
             if(average_no_lowest > 90)
                  System.out.print('A');
             else if(average_no_lowest < 90 && average_no_lowest > 80 )
                  System.out.print('B');
             else if(average_no_lowest > 70 && average_no_lowest < 80)
                  System.out.print('C'); 
             else
                  System.out.print('D');
             }
       else if (score3 < score1 && score3 < score2){
             average_no_lowest =(score1 + score3)/2.0;
             System.out.println("The average without the lowest score is: " + (score1 + score3)/2.0);
             if(average_no_lowest > 90)
                  System.out.print('A');
             else if(average_no_lowest < 90 && average_no_lowest > 80 )
                  System.out.print('B');
             else if(average_no_lowest > 70 && average_no_lowest < 80)
                  System.out.print('C'); 
             else
                  System.out.print('D');     
             }

    }
}
</code>
```

Comment: Your condition is most probably broken, what if the value happens to be exactly 90 or 80? Then you can replace the range tests like `else if (x<=90 && x>80)` by `else if (x>80)` and so make it a bit readable.

Answer (score 5):

Your section of code which reads

```
if(average_no_lowest > 90)
    System.out.print('A');
else if(average_no_lowest < 90 && average_no_lowest > 80 )
    System.out.print('B');
else if(average_no_lowest > 70 && average_no_lowest < 80)
    System.out.print('C'); 
else
    System.out.print('D');
}
```

is duplicated 3 times. Put it into a method.

Don't be worried about performance until it is a proven problem. Be worried about how easy it is to read and maintain the code.

Code has 2 audiences - the compiler and humans. Humans matter more than compilers.

Comment: upvote for the remark `Code has 2 audiences - the compiler and humans. Humans matter more than compilers.`

Comment: `Code has 2 audiences - the compiler and humans. Humans matter more than compilers.` Classic !

Comment: I'm not sure how to do methods yet.For now I can only use if-else statements.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know how novice you were, but I must commend you on your instincts and "wondering if it could be more efficient". Yes it could, including using an ArrayList and sorting and other things. But I'd wait until you are more familiar with the basics before getting into that stuff. Make your code easy for a stranger to read, and you'll never be wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

Store the lowest score in a variable e.g. lowest_score.
and do the average by (total - lowest_score) / 2
It is the most efficient

Comment: @tom that is mathematically incorrect , if u remove one data item and get the average of the remaining data items its not the same as getting with all the data items. Consider following example

Data( 1 , 2, 3)  , if one removes the lowest score(i.e 1) , and deduct from total (6-1) you are left with 5/2 =2.5 average according to your function, but if all 3 data items were considered on taking average it would be (1+2+3)/2= 2  , so two different answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,these have fewer lines of code and gives the same output as you want::

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int score1, score2, score3, status;
    double average, average_no_lowest;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter three scores: ");
    score1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    score2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    score3 = keyboard.nextInt();

    average = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
    System.out.println("Average Score was:: " + average);

    if (score1 < score2 && score1 < score3) {
        status = 1;
        System.out.println("The lowest score was:: " + score1);
    } else if (score2 < score1 && score2 < score3) {
        status = 2;
        System.out.println("The lowest score was:: " + score2);
    } else {
        status = 3;
        System.out.println("The lowest score was:: " + score3);
    }

    if (status == 1) {
        average_no_lowest = (score2 + score3) / 2;
        System.out.println("The average without the lowest score is: "
                + average_no_lowest);
    } else if (status == 2) {
        average_no_lowest = (score1 + score3) / 2;
        System.out.println("The average without the lowest score is: "
                + average_no_lowest);
    } else {
        average_no_lowest = (score1 + score2) / 2;
        System.out.println("The average without the lowest score is: "
                + average_no_lowest);
    }

}
```